# images are not comming up on user product page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

when i add image on admin page for a product . it is uploading successfully and uploaded image is reflected (saves)  on  correct folder

**But when i run user portal and sees products . The product images are not showing up**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request) {
    bookService.save(book);

    MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();

    try {
        byte[] bytes = bookImage.getBytes();
        String name = book.getId() + ".png";
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/book/" + name)));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:bookList";
}
```

[Product Page image issue < you can find it Here>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpL5J.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with more info on how are you displaying the image; the <img/> tag to be specific.

Comment: <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
         <img class="img-responsive shelf-book" th:src="#{adminPath}+@{/image/book}+${book.id}+'.png'"/>
        </div>

Comment: When you view the source in a browser, what do your image tag contain for `src`?

Comment: in browser i am getting like this                   <img class="img-responsive shelf-book" src="http://localhost:8081/adminportal/image/book9.png">

Comment: i think if you get your image over localhost:8081 you must place it in the `/public` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the path where you are saving the images.

When the application is running, it ignores the `src` directory and refers to the `target` directory and your images are being uploaded in `src/main/java/resources/static/image`. If you copy the images manually to the path `target/classes/static/image`, the images will be displayed properly.

And I **absolutely do not recommend** saving the images in the `target` directory, because doing a maven clean will delete that directory. To give it a try, open a terminal/command prompt on the root directory of your project and execute the command `mvn clean`.

I would strongly advice you to save the images somewhere else, like 'C:\projectName\images' and make the path configurable via `application.properties` or via a configuration saved in the db.